# Is there a way from which I can call script from GIT repo in Jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline Job in which I have mentioned GHE repo1 where my pipeline script is written.  Now in my pipeline script in GHE repo1 I want to call one nodejs script which I have kept in GHE repo2. How I can call from this remote repo2 which is not mentioned in my Jenkins Job? I tried cloning repo2 in my pipeline script but it gives error

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/Myorg/repo2.git
Cloning into 'repo2'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: the error is telling what the issue is, you need to have the public key on the jenkins machine to be able to clone the git repo. Currently you do not have access to clone

Comment: I can clone this repo on my local machine. How Can I clone in Pipeline script. How to deal with SSH key? I have SSH key in Jenkins credentials.

Comment: This can be done using the checkout, then using the credentials part. Check the checkout step in pipeline

Comment: I was able to do using below:

stages
  {
       stage('Clone gre-admin-cli ')
       { 
            steps
            {
              dir('gre-admin-cli') 
              {
                 git url: 'git@github.ibm.com:Bluemix-Admin/gre-admin-cli.git',
                 branch: 'master',
                 credentialsId: 'c37cf275-afc4-4131-b9c1-f7d61d2f9b8b'
              }
           }
       }
     }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do by using below code:

```
stages
  {
       stage('Clone repo1')
       { 
            steps
            {
              dir('repo1') 
              {
                 git url: 'XXXXXXX',
                 branch: 'master',
                 credentialsId: 'XXXXXXX'
              }
           }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also save the other SSH key in the Jenkins Credentials and then use native git commands (works in scripted pipeline, I don't know about declarative pipeline):

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: <credentials_name>, keyFileVariable: 'SSHKEYFILE')]) {
    sh("ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add ${env.SSHKEYFILE}; git clone <url>'") // replace 'sh' with 'bat' if using windows
}
```

This requires the git executable in the path variable of the build agent. I am using it with git for windows.

EDIT: This is a potential security issue because the SSH key is saved in a file and could be read by other jobs!!